# DatePicker angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I have `datepicker` with [Angular](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) . here is the question:

How can to prevent user write to in input? I just want to let user add date from pop up.

Comment: just make disabled or readonly property to the field ..so user cant able to enter datas in it..

Comment: check the answer below , that's the easy way

Comment: This is not related to angular

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use readonly propery of html

```html
<input type="text" readonly>
```